# promise Q not working consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, q

Im using the Q library of promise and I've some basic question 
I've created this code and when I omit the first return  Q word I got error (return Q(100)),but for the second and the third there is no problem if I omit them, the code is still working,why?

```
  function firstFn() {
        return Q(100);
    };


    function secFn(){
        return Q(200);
    };

    function thirdFn(){
        return q(300);
    };


    firstFn().then(function(a){
        alert(a);
        return secFn();
    }).then(function(b){
        alert(b);
        return thirdFn();
    }).then(function(c){
        alert(c)
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on what Robert Levy has said:

The Promises/A+ specifiaction which specifies how Q's then works dictates that whenever a value is returned from a `.then` callback it is unwrapped as a promise.

What calling `Q(foo)` does, which is similar to what `Promise.resolve(foo)` does is wrap things as a promise. So Q(100) is a promise over the value 100. Whenver a value is returned from a `then` callback, it is "wrapped".

```
Q(100); 
Q().then(function(){ return 100; }); // the same as the line above
Q.try(function(){ return 100; }); // same as line above
// or in ES6 native promises or bluebird promises
Promise.resolve(100);
Promise.resolve().then(function(){ return 100; }); // the same as the line above
```

---

To be perfectly clear, the spec says about the `.then` callback arguments:

> If either `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` returns a value x, run the Promise Resolution Procedure [[Resolve]](promise2, x).

The Promise Resolution Procedure states:

> If x is a promise, adopt its state [3.4]: (note mine: not our case)
>
> Otherwise, if x is an object or function,
>
> - Let `then` be `x.then`. [3.5]
> - if `then` is not a function, fulfill promise with x

So, Q is OK in doing this, this makes our life easier and allows us to assimilate values as promises. The reasoning is that we want to keep the appearance of `.then` chains async, so returning a value is really just fulfilling the the new promise we're wrapping

Comment: 1+ for elaborting :) ,just to verify that I got it,Q is identical to then with Q but like writing it in short.if so how do you chain using Q? im not talking about Q.all since the order is importent...

Comment: @AlBundy the way to chain with promises is to use `.then` - think of `.then` as an abstraction over semicolons - it's how chaining works in promises. `firstFn().then(secondFn).then(thirdFn)` - consider looking at promise tutorials - they usually cover this :)

Comment: Im talking about the example you wrote Q(100); 
Q().then(function(){ return 100; });  ,which the first is the same with the second line,assume I want to use the first line (Q(100)),how should I chain with this syntax ,please provide example.Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean something like `Q(100).then(function(v){ console.log(v); return Q(200); }).then(function(x){ console.log(x); return Q(300); })`

Comment: @AlBundy I just gave you an upvote which means [you can now chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) - if you have specifics you'd like to discuss you're welcome to ask there. I'd rather not put other 'too specific' content in the comments since it makes things harder for future users who read this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking .then(function(a)...) on the value returned from firstFn so it needs to return something that has a .then function on it.

For the the other 2 functions, you are invoking them within a Q .then() callback.  If you return a promise from those callbacks, Q will take advantage of them but if you don't return anything, Q is ok with that too.